# Failed to connect to mysql at 127.0.0.1:3306 with user root@localhost

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mysql-workbench

Tell me why it doesn't work? I've looked all over and can't connect

[image]

I found this answer https://askubuntu.com/questions/773446/unable-to-connect-via-mysql-workbench-to-localhost-in-ubuntu-16-04-passwordless

Comment: Please share more details, like the error message in text form and your attempts to resolve the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allow your ip address to remote access in your db if not done yet:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'your_machine_ip' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Comment: If the OP cannot get into MySQL with the root account, please tell us how they are going to change the privileges on this or any other account

Comment: From the image[first terminal],I can see that the OP has already accessed into MySQL console.